# Regex: need to have substring A, not have substring B, and not end with substring C

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, regex-lookarounds

I've only just started with regex over the last couple days and am currently stumped. Checked Google and Stack-- for answers but no luck...

Given the following list:

- district_code,
- county_district_code,
- CoDis,
- Dist,
- Dist Code,
- DistCode,
- -
- educational_service_district,
- District,
- District Name,
- DistrictName,
- County Code,

I need to find any entries that meet *all* the following criteria:

- contain 'dist' or 'codis'
- do not contain 'name'
- do not end with 'district'

From that first list you'll see items beyond the dash should be filtered out, but I'm having trouble with my third criteria of ignoring entries ending in 'district'... the regex keeps catching 'educational_service_district' and 'District' despite my (probably incorrect) usage of a negative lookahead for 'district'. I'm working in Python 3.6.1 and the best I've been able to come up with is the following (I'm using the case-insensitive flag BTW)

```
^.*(dist|codis)(?!.*name).*(?!district$)$
```

Thanks in advance for your help. Here's the entirety of the code I'm using (just in case I did something stupid that isn't regex related):

```
import re

sample = ["district_code", "county_district_code", "CoDis", "Dist", "Dist Code", "DistCode", "educational_service_district", "District", "District Name", 
"DistrictName", "County Code"]

regex = "^.*(dist|codis)(?!.*name).*(?!district$)$"
regex = re.compile(regex, re.IGNORECASE)

for x in sample:
    if re.match(regex, x):
        print('Regex query', regex, 'matched sample text', x)
```

Comment: regex is probably not the best tool to use here; you can actually do this with just something like `("dist" in x or "codis" in x) and "name" not in x and not x.endswith("district")`

Comment: True; I had hoped to avoid using regex for this. The problem is the full script I'm writing iterates over a CSV that contains a list of regex queries that are each performed against the main list. For example, some of the other regex queries that'll get run include: `^(district)+(?!.*count)` and `^(?=.*county)(?!.*name)`... so if there's a way to do this with regex I'd prefer that over rewriting all those regex lists

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regex seems to face issue where it matches the 'dist' in a 'district' at the end of a line, capturing the dist and preventing the negative lookahead from finding that line ending district. We can avoid this by moving all the negative lookaheads to the beginning of the regex.

```
^(?!.*(?:name|district$)).*(dist|codis).*$
```

https://regex101.com/r/dwfi7b/1

Note: I used the multiline flag in regex101 because I presented the test cases as a newline delimited list, using the array of strings and for-loop prevents this need.